# TryGetValue returns Null even though key exists?

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, null, trygetvalue

I have a few dictionary objects being combed through to get a value but all of them return null even though when I check to see if they contain the key the one that has the key returns true. I can also use a foreach to go through each one to get the value based on that key....I'm so lost

```
foreach (var item in treeView.SelectedItems)
{
    string reportName = item.Header.ToString();
    string reportPath = "";

    reportsAvail.TryGetValue(reportName, out reportPath);
    reports.TryGetValue(reportName, out reportPath);
    additionalReports.TryGetValue(reportName, out reportPath);

    bool test; 

    test = reportsAvail.ContainsKey(reportName);
    test = reports.ContainsKey(reportName);
    test = additionalReports.ContainsKey(reportName);

    foreach (var y in reportsAvail)
    {
        if (y.Key.ToString() == reportName)
        {
            textBlock1.Text = y.Value;
            reportPath = y.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

What's weird is it USED to work...I'm not sure what's stopping it

Comment: Did you assign `null` as the value of that key in the dictionary?

Comment: what is reports ? type ?... tru reports.Items[key] that should return if it exists..

Comment: Your `foreach` is only going through `reportsAvail`, though in your debugging lines you're checking two other dictionaries. Are you sure that's the dictionary it's in?

Comment: Check the case, it is case sensitive. put trim on key as well.

Comment: its a dictionary<string, string>

@Servy When I check the dictionary during debugging it shows they key I'm looking for is there. The dictionary has no null keys or values

Comment: You are using `TryGetValue` three times and you're overwriting `reportPath` each time. So even if the first or second contained the `reportName`, if the third didn't contain it `reportPath` will be `null` again.

Comment: @AdamV you are correct, I didn't make the other two right now because I was testing with something in reportsAvail before posting. I had done the other 2 before and they worked fine.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I bet that's it. I didn't even think of that. I will shove it in a switch and see if that goes anywhere!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `TryGetValue` three times and you're overwriting `reportPath` each time. So even if the first or second contained the `reportName`, if the third didn't contain it `reportPath` will be `null` again.

Maybe this fixes it:

```
bool reportFound = reportsAvail.TryGetValue(reportName, out reportPath);
if(!reportFound)
    reportFound = reports.TryGetValue(reportName, out reportPath);
if(!reportFound)
    reportFound = additionalReports.TryGetValue(reportName, out reportPath);
```

Comment: thought so but "Used to Work" put me off

Comment: @Muds: it could be that by now `additionalReports` contained the report-name which hides the issue.

Comment: @Muds yeah I remember now that I was only looking up a single report dictionary instead of all three. I've been staring at this window for 2 weeks and had just forgot basics like not overwriting values haha